# I am facing the problem to install react-currency-format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependencies, currency-formatting

I I'm facing the issue for install react- currency- format because of latest version of react 18 i can easily install with the help of force save....but i have doubts if i m doing this then it will creat issues with my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently the react-currency-format does not work with the 18.0.0 and above to get the react-currency format to work you will need to downgrade your react to react ^17.0.0 in your package.json file after deleting your package-lock.json

another option is to add --force to the end of the install command like so

```
npm install react-currency-format --save --force
```

or you can also use

```
npm i react-currency-format --save --force
```

Your Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! Here is a set of questions can work as clarification, for your kind information.

Ques: Is react-currency-format well maintained?

Ans: We found indications that react-currency-format maintenance is sustainable demonstrating some project activity. We saw a total of 20 open source contributors collaborating on the project.

Ques: Is react-currency-format safe to use?

Ans: The npm package react-currency-format was scanned for known vulnerabilities and missing license, and no issues were found. Thus the package was deemed as safe to use.

Hope both of above mentioned q/a gives you a "aha" moment.

Reference: https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/react-currency-format